# How to interpret Box-Cox Transformation

Tags: regression, data-transformation, interpretation

I have used a Box-Behnken experimental design. I have a full quadratic model.

However, I had to transform the response, $Y$ for the model to fit; I did this using a Box-Cox transformation with $\lambda=0.5$.

For example, one of the regressions is like this:

$$Y = 1.28 - 0.008X_1-0.025X_2-0.05X_3-0.13X_1^2-0.01X_2^2-0.006X_3^2\\
+0.02X_1X_2-0.05X_1X_3+0.09X_2X_3$$

How do I interpret the terms?

Comment: Which variable(s) were transformed?

Comment: @glen the Y variable

Comment: user43075 I have taken a gamble and assumed that @IrishStat has guessed correctly (it would be my guess also), but could you confirm? [If that's not the case your question will need to be edited.]